# what does changeit really do in java net ssl keystore?

Tags: java, security, ssl

I saw the config like this below, the `changeit` really a password? or it will look for some encypted password file? Or it has special meaning to the keystore/truststore?

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=as-install/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=as-install/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

I knew it is default password for java cacert, but is there any other meaning?

Comment: It sounds like you need to *changeit* to your actual password ?

Comment: but it is java options, where to change it? does it look for some special encrpyted file?

Comment: It is the default password of cacerts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a keystore or a truststore with the java keytool.exe, changeit is the default password of the keystore or truststore, but you should change it.

When you want to use the keystore or truststore you have to tell the application the password as you did with the -D flag.